# Нужны ли тут запятые и где?

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно с точки зрения пунктуации оформить предложение "Три недели с мамой по решению суда едва не сломали психику 3-летнему ребенку". Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Данное предложение некорректно для любого стиля (публицистического, делового, разговорного), поэтому его следует как-то изменить (одни знаки препинания не помогут).

Исправленный вариант в качестве примера:

"Три недели, проведенные по решению суда с мамой, едва не сломали психику 3-летнему ребенку".

Answer (score 0):

Здесь имеет место упрощение: не обозначено глаголом или причастием действие, выполненное по решению суда (проведенные 3 недели). Поэтому для связи "решения суда" с остальным лучше применить тире, сделав схематичное упоминание о решении вставкой:

Три недели с мамой - по решению суда - едва не сломали психику 3-летнему ребенку.

Comment: Спасибо, Алекс. А вот так - без знаков препинания, не допустимо вообще? Ошибка? Или можно выделять, а можно и не выделять?

Comment: Без знаков можно придраться, сказав, что решение суда связано не только с 3 неделями, но и со сломом психики ("сломали" - единственный глагол и "решение" невольно с ним связывается при прочтении). Другой вариант - ввести причастный оборот (Три недели, по решению суда проведённые с мамой, ...).

Comment: Ок, спасибо, Алекс. Вы нам очень помогли :)